# How to play local mp3 file on iOS Phonegap

Tags: ios, audio, cordova, local-storage

I'm trying to play some local mp3 files with my iPhone in my PhoneGap app. The sound files are located in assets/www/cssScript/sound/.. 
I tested on my iPhone when I used it as a developer device connected to my computer, then everything worked perfectly. However, when I tested after downloading the app on another iPhone it did not work, which I think is very strange. Is the way Im doing it in my code correct? Are there any other ways to do this? All help will be deeply appreciated.

To play the sound I use this code

```
function playAudioBuy(sound) {
       // sound is for example click.mp3

       var path = window.location.pathname;

    var phoneGapPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var path2 = phoneGapPath + 'cssScript/sound/' + sound; 

var my_media = new Media(path2,
    // success callback
    function () {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    },
    // error callback
    function (err) {
        for(var i in err){
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err.message + " error code " + err.code);
        }
    }
);
// Play audio
my_media.play();
}
```